# Object Reference not set to instance of an object (CacheRequest)(UI)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, ui-automation

Hi I am using this code to read datagridview cell.Its working fine till

```
       var myString = targetText.Cached.Name;
```

targettext is null

Code:

```
       LogMessage("Getting RootElement...");
        AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.RootElement;
        if (rootElement != null)
        {
            LogMessage("OK." + Environment.NewLine);

            Automation.Condition condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Form1");

            LogMessage("Searching for Test Window...");
            AutomationElement appElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);

            if (appElement != null)
            {
                LogMessage("OK " + Environment.NewLine);
                LogMessage("Searching for Gridview control...");
                AutomationElement txtElementA = GetTextElement(appElement, "dg");
                var rows = txtElementA.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, PropertyCondition.TrueCondition);
                foreach (AutomationElement loginLine in rows)
                {
                    var loginLinesDetails = loginLine.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Custom));

                    for (var i = 0; i < loginLinesDetails.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var cacheRequest = new CacheRequest
                        {
                            AutomationElementMode = AutomationElementMode.None,
                            TreeFilter = System.Windows.Automation.Automation.RawViewCondition
                        };

                        cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
                        cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty);

                        cacheRequest.Push();

                        var targetText = loginLinesDetails[i].FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TextBlock"));// targettext is null

                        cacheRequest.Pop();

                        var myString = targetText.Cached.Name;//Object reference not set ///to instance of an object error
                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                WriteLogError();
            }
        }
```

Here is an image of an example form i am trying to read at present.If it works for this small app it will definately work for big apps.

[image]

All I want to do is read the cells of a datagridview.I dont know whether I am doing right or not can any one please help me with this.
There would be great appreciation if someone could help me

Comment: it isnt a duplicate please read the question once again not the heading

Comment: Have you tried checking if targettext is null? If its null you should not access it, it will give you Object reference not set... error. I think what akshay has suggested makes sense

Comment: yeah i am getting null on that line.how can i get a value in that line inspite of null.Am i doing something wrong

Comment: @IshaqGi It's a duplicate because the problem we're talking about is the same of the linked question. Debug the line where you have the null reference. The line `loginLinesDetails[i].FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TextBlock"));` is returning you a null object. Check that line.

Comment: yes you are right I am getting a null value at that line.what should i do to get the cell value in that line instead of null value?

Comment: @IshaqGi: If the object is `null` then there *is no* value.  `null` is the very definition of a lack of a value.

Answer (score 3):

Before you try to assign value to

```
var myString = targetText.Cached.Name;
```

Check following condition

```
if(targetText != null && targetText.Cached!=null)
   var myString = targetText.Cached.Name;
```

Might be the case that following line is returning `NULL`

```
loginLinesDetails[i].FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TextBlock"));
```

Comment: I have updated my question can you please have a look at it sorry i forgot to mention that targettext is null

Comment: @ Ishaq Gi That is why you getting exception. As you are trying to access values in NULL. like null.Cached.Name.

Comment: yeah i am getting null on that line.how can i get a value in that line inspite of null.Am i doing something wrong Akshay ?

Comment: there is'nt anything such as loginLinesDetails[i].FirstOrDefault in the reference.how did you get that ?

Comment: I just updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: no you havent updated the answer @Akshay have a glance at it

Comment: this is a valid answer to this question. Handle the null or examine the line returning the null value. As for me this answer is valid.

Comment: but why i am getting an null value i've updated my question with a picture of a form which i want to read as an example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem *might* be that you are looking for a `TextBox` control, as suggested by the line

```
LogMessage("Searching for TextBox A control...");
```

but in the `PropertyCondition` you use `"TextBlock"` as class name.

Then you should write this:

```
var targetText = loginLinesDetails[i].FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TextBox")); // here
```